# why do i have a corrupted image file after using move_uploaded_file function

Tags: php, forms, file, global-variables

I have a form:

```
<form action='' enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

I have php code:

```
$file = $_FILES['image']
$ext = explode(",", $file['type'])[0];
$location = "../image/movedimage.$ext";
if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $location)) echo 'moved';
else echo 'internal error';
```

This echos "moved" but the problem is that when I check the path to which the file was moved, the image file in there is corrupted.

I had to change the system of uploading the image by doing this:

```
 $file_content = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);
 $file_dump = file_put_contents($location, $file_content);
```

This attempt of placing the file directly using the `file_put_contents` works fine and the image file is perfect just as uploaded but using the `move_uploaded_file` leaves a corrupted file in the destination folder. I would like to understand why this is happening as the `$file['error']` returns a value `0` and the `move_uploaded_file` function does not return `false`.

Comment: do you know how it's corrupted? you could open the moved file with a text editor, check top and bottom for anything unusual.

Comment: The file cannot be opened by text editor.

Comment: care to expand, there's a lot of unknowns your not  sharing

Answer (score 0):

In your code by using

```
$ext = explode(",", $file['type'])[0];
```

you get the extension as `image/your_image_type`.
Then you are appending that with the file name, which will create an invalid image.
To get the extension, you can do as follows

```
$ext= explode("/", $file['type'])[1];
```

or

```
$ext = strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));
```

Comment: ummm... Sorry but the `explode(",", $file['type'])[0]` was actually an error in my syntax here. I literally made use of the `"/"`  and echoed the result which outputted `../image/movedimage.jpeg` but that made no observable change